# Is it possible to scale an entire \begin{figure}?

Tags: floats, scaling

I have a bunch of LaTeX-output from Gnuplot which I would *really* like to leave alone. Is there an easy way of scaling an entire figure?

Something like

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{...}
```

but just for the `figure` environment?

If it matters, I have

```
\begin{figure}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{figure}
```

and the output is from gnuplot used "set terminal latex" and so on.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You are looking for the macros

- `\resizebox{<h-length>}{<v-length>}{<content>}` and
- `\scalebox{<h-scale>}[<v-scale>]{<content>}`

from the
[`graphics`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics)/[`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) packages (→ [`graphics` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/graphics), 3.3 “Scaling”, p. 3).

The `\scalebox` macro expects ratios like those you’d use in `\includegraphics`, you you would be using

```
\begin{figure}
    \scalebox{.5}{\input{plot.tex}}
\end{figure}
```

or, if you rather want to resize the content to a fixed width (or height),

```
\begin{figure}
    \resizebox{.9\linewidth}{!}{\input{plot.tex}}
\end{figure}
```

where `!` means that the content gets resized so that it keeps its aspect ratio.

There exist also a starred version of `\resizebox` and you can use the lengths `\height`, `\width`, `\totalheight` and `\depth` to refer to the original sizes of the content; meaning the factor `.5` could be used with `\resizebox`, too:

```
\begin{figure}
    \resizebox{.5\totalheight}{!}{\input{plot.tex}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this from outside of the `figure` environment?

Comment: `\scalebox` also works with .pstex_t files exported from xfig (the .pstex_t file includes --with `\includegraphics`-- a .pstex file). `\resizebox` does not work.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using subfigures that are scaled and want non-subfigure plots to match the others' layout, you can use the subfigure code as well with just one plot:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.95\textwidth}
     \include{plot.tex}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{
    My caption...
  }
  \label{fig:myPlot}
\end{figure}
```

(In my case, using the other suggested answer left some components of the plot not matching -- maybe axis labels or legend, I forget -- thus my hacky approach.)

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ratio\textwidth` can be an easier solution for resizing the figure.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figures.png}
    \caption{in 0.45, you can use any ratio that fits your single figure}
    \label{fig:label01}
\end{figure}
```