# Rescaling in the picture environment including text

Tags: diagrams

Is there a way to rescale the picture environment in TeX (and yes by setting \unitlength), but so that the included text also scales? I have some rather complicated pictures with many draw line etc. commands, which now need to be fitted in a smaller space. The text could easily be seen if it was a smaller size. Is there a way to rescale everything equally?

Comment: The graphicx package includes \scalebox and \resizebox.

Comment: Duplicat? [Is it possible to scale an entire \begin{figure}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98142/124842)