# How can I reduce the size of an electric circuit in Circuitikz?

Tags: scaling, circuitikz

In fact, I have drawn an electric scheme using circuitikz package, but when I try to reduce the size of the circuit by using a scale of 0.5, the electric components stay in their size. Because I want to display two circuits one next to the other. Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.2][american voltages]
\draw

 (0,0) to [open,v>=${v}_{ds}$] (0,4) 
  to [short, *- ,i=${i}_{ds}$] (0.5,4)
  to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,4) 
  to [L, l=$X_s$] (4,4)
  to [european voltage source, l_=${\omega}_s {\phi}_{qs}$] (4.5,4)
  (4.5,4) to [short, -] (5,4)
  (5,4) to [L, l_=$X_m$] (5,0)

  (5,4) to [european voltage source, l_=${\omega}_r {\phi}_{qr}$] (6.5,4)
  to [L, l=$X_r$] (7.5,4)
  to [R, l=$R_r$] (9.8,4)
  to [short, -* ,i<=${i}_{dr}$] (10,4) 
  (10,0) to [open, v>=${v}_{dr}$] (10,4)
  (0,0) to [short, *-*] (10,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
  \end{document}
```

And here is the change in the figure below:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32156/scaling-components-in-circuitikz... Also if you don't care about the fontsize on the letters you can use these ways: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98142/120578

Comment: `scale=0.5,transform shape`, but the text will be resized as well.

Comment: Thank you so very much guys it works well, please another thing if you look to the previous figure (the right one) the iqr arrow is not in the middle as the current iqs how can I make it in the middle ? And last thing I have tried to add an arrow on the top of omega_s{\phi}_{qs} but an error was displayed I have tried to follow the same way I did with the voltage vsq and vqr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see if this help:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5][american voltages]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}
```

**addendum:** however, i would redraw you image (on more consistent way, all in european style) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[straightvoltages, european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[ scale=0.5,          % i would rather scale 0.6, if possible
                        font=\footnotesize  % <-- smaller font
                        ]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=7mm}               % <-- smaller bipole elements
%
\draw   (0,0)   to [open,v>=$v_{ds}$] (0,4)
                to [short, *- ,i=$i_{ds}$] (0.5,4)
                to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,4)
                to [L, l=$X_s$] (3.5,4)
                to [V, l_=$\omega_s \phi_{qs}$] (5,4)
        (5,4)   to [short] (5.5,4)

        (5.25,4)to [L, l_=$X_m$, *-*] (5.25,0)

        (5.5,4) to [V, l_=$\omega_r \phi_{qr}$] (7,4)
                to [L, l=$X_r$] (8.5,4)
                to [R, l=$R_r$] (10,4)
                to [short, -* ,i<=$i_{dr}$] (10.5,4)
                to [open, v^<=$v_{dr}$] (10.5,0)
        (0,0)   to [short, *-*] (10.5,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko please How can I adjust the idr arrow in the middle as ids ?

Comment: @twimo, you draw $_{ds} in `short` with lenght of 5mm (between `(0,4)` and `(0.5,4)`), however the length of `short` with $_{dr} is  only 2mm (between  `(9.8,4)` and `(10,4)`. enlarge `(10,4)` to   `(10.3,4)` and similarly bottom terminal from `(10,0)` to `(10.3,0)`.

Comment: @twimo, now i added complete code for your image. now you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer), of course if it solve your problem, or at least up-vote it (by clicking on up-pen at the top left side of answer) :-). on this way is here expressed "thank you" ...