# Changing the form of the arrow head in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, circuitikz

In fact, in this code below you can see that the arrows under the omega{\phi} is different from the arrows of the voltages. I want to have similar arrows to the voltages one.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{lscape,array}


\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5][american voltages]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}
\draw

(0,0) to [open,v>=$v_{ds}$] (0,5) 

to [short, *- ,i=$i_{ds}$] (0.3,5)
to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,5) 
to [L, l=$X_s$] (3.2,5)
to [european voltage source, l^=$\omega_s \phi_{qs}$] (4.9,5)
(4.5,5) to [short, -] (5,5)
(5,5) to [L, l_=$X_m$] (5,0)


(5,5) to [european voltage source, l^=$\omega_r \phi_{qr}$] (7,5)
to [L, l=$X_r$] (8,5)
to [R, l=$R_r$] (10,5)
to [short, -* ,i<=$i_{dr}$] (10.3,5) 
(10.3,0) to [open, v>=$v_{dr}$] (10.3,5)
(0,0) to [short, *-*] (10.3,0);
\draw[->](3.5,4.3) -- (4.9,4.3);
\draw[->](6.5,4.3) -- (5.1,4.3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

package `arrows.meta` provide many diferent of arrows heads

try with

```
\draw[-Triangle]    (3.5,4.3) -- (4.9,4.3);
\draw[-Triangle]    (6.5,4.3) -- (5.1,4.3);
```

and replace `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` with `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}`.

complete document considering [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414562/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-an-electric-circuit-in-circuitikz/414568#414568):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[straightvoltages, european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[ scale=0.5,          % i would rather scale 0.6, if possible
                        font=\footnotesize  % <-- smaller font
                        ]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=7mm}               % <-- smaller bipole elements
%
\draw   (0,0)   to [open,v>=$v_{ds}$] (0,4)
                to [short, *- ,i=$i_{ds}$] (0.5,4)
                to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,4)
                to [L, l=$X_s$] (3.5,4)
                to [V, l^=$\omega_s \phi_{qs}$] (5,4)
        (5,4)   to [short] (5.5,4)

        (5.25,4)to [L, l_=$X_m$, *-*] (5.25,0)

        (5.5,4) to [V, l^=$\omega_r \phi_{qr}$] (7,4)
                to [L, l=$X_r$] (8.5,4)
                to [R, l=$R_r$] (10,4)
                to [short, -* ,i<=$i_{dr}$] (10.5,4)
                to [open, v^<=$v_{dr}$] (10.5,0)
        (0,0)   to [short, *-*] (10.5,0);
\draw[-Triangle]    (3.5,3.3) -- + ( 1.5,0);
\draw[-Triangle]    (7.0,3.3) -- + (-1.5,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**note.**
mixing the american and european style of drawing the electric/electronic circuits is consider as bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{lscape,array}


\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5][american voltages]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.8cm}
\draw

(0,0) to [open,v>=$v_{ds}$] (0,5) 

to [short, *- ,i=$i_{ds}$] (0.3,5)
to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,5) 
to [L, l=$X_s$] (3.2,5)
to [european voltage source, l^=$\omega_s \phi_{qs}$] (4.9,5)
(4.5,5) to [short, -] (5,5)
(5,5) to [L, l_=$X_m$] (5,0)


(5,5) to [european voltage source, l^=$\omega_r \phi_{qr}$] (7,5)
to [L, l=$X_r$] (8,5)
to [R, l=$R_r$] (10,5)
to [short, -* ,i<=$i_{dr}$] (10.3,5) 
(10.3,0) to [open, v>=$v_{dr}$] (10.3,5)
(0,0) to [short, *-*] (10.3,0);
\draw[-latex](3.5,4.3) -- (4.9,4.3);
\draw[-latex](6.5,4.3) -- (5.1,4.3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

These arrows look to me like the standard `latex` arrows provided by Ti*k*Z. If you want all arrows to be like this, just use `\tikzet{>=latex}` somewhere in the beginning of the document.

Comment: it seems that we are now extremely good synchronized (on 12 h of time zone distance :-) ) ...

Comment: @Zarko Looks like it. Notice that I am very slow during hibernation time ;-)

Comment: i very much doubt that you have a hibernation period. even worse, do you even ever sleep? you are super-active and extremely fast :-). go, go marmots!

Comment: @Zarko Of course I [hibernate](http://marmots.org/groundhog-day-2018-meet-van-is-violet/).